# Data not being passed from parent to child. (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, parent-child

I am currently making a Trello Clone. It has been going well so far and I've had a lot of help from everyone here, so thank you!

My current issue is that I am trying to pass the state of `modalData` in `App.js` to `<ModifyModal />`.

I have tried researching and Googling, and even re-writing functions and creating new ones. However, nothing had worked. I know that the state is being updated with the correct text since I made the title from `Trello Clone!` to `{modalData}` and it worked. I want the data of `modalData` to be passed from `App.js` to `<ModifyModal />`.

**Edit:** Made  a functional component and it is still showing undefined for the data.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Todobox from './Todobox';
import ModifyModal from './ModifyModal';
import Item from './Item';

const Widget = ({parentCallback2}) => <Todobox parentCallback2={parentCallback2}/>

const Widget2 = () => <ModifyModal />

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleCallback = this.handleCallback.bind(this);

    this.state={
      elements: [],
      modal: [],
      modalData: null
    }
  }

  // Creates new element box
  handleNewElement = () => {
    const newElement = [...this.state.elements, Widget];
    this.setState({
      elements: newElement
    });
  }

  handleCallback = (itemWidget, itemData) =>{
    const newModal = [...this.state.modal, itemWidget];
    const newData = itemData;
    this.setState({
      modal: newModal,
      modalData: newData
    });
  }

  render() { 
    const { elements, modal, modalData } = this.state;
    return (
    <>
    <div className='page-container'>
      <div className='header'>
        <a className='header-title'>{modalData}</a>
        <a className='header-button' onClick={this.handleNewElement.bind(this)}>Create a list</a>
      </div>
      <div className='element-field'>
        {elements.length !== 0 &&
          elements.map((Widget, i) => <Widget key={i} parentCallback2={this.handleCallback}/>)}
      </div>
    </div>
          {modal.length !== 0 &&
            modal.map((Widget2, i) => <Widget2 key={i} itemDataToChild={modalData} />)}
    </>
    );
  }
}
 
export default App;
```

ModifyModal.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import trash from './trash_can.png';
import './App.css'

function ModifyModal({ itemDataToChild }){
    const [hideModal, setHideModal] = useState(false);
    const [content, setContent] = useState(itemDataToChild);

    const handleCancel = () =>{
        setHideModal(true);
    }

    return(
        <>
        <div className={`modify-modal-container ${hideModal ? 'modify-modal-container-hide' : ''}`}>
            <div className='modify-modal'>
                <a className='modify-title'>{content}</a>
                <textarea className='modify-input' />
                    <div className='modify-buttons'>
                        <a className='modify-btn' id='modify-update-btn'>Update</a>
                        <a className='modify-btn' id='modify-cancel-btn' onClick={handleCancel}>Cancel</a>
                        <img src={trash} id='modify-delete'/>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default ModifyModal;
```

Any help is appreciated since I am new to this. :)

Comment: Can you give a little bit more information about what's not working exactly? Is it that the data in the `<ModifyModal />` component is undefined or something like that?

Comment: Also, some free advice based on your code: take a look at [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), these are now the preferred way to setup a component instead of a class.

In the `<ModifyModal />` component you receive some props and you directly convert these props into a state object. This is considered an anti-pattern and you [probably don't need it](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)

Comment: @n9iels Yes, when trying to pass data to ‘<ModifyModal />’ it is undefined and not working. Also so I should setup a component as a function instead of class?

Comment: If you want to send data between components that has no direct relation, you can use [React Context](https://www.taniarascia.com/using-context-api-in-react/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you declared and initialized Widget2.

```js
const Widget2 = () => <ModifyModal />
```

What is actually happening under the hood is that Widget2 received a function which returns a JSX.Element, it didn't actually become ModifyModal, the functional component.If you look at the line above is actually doing right.

`const Widget = ({parentCallback2}) => <Todobox parentCallback2={parentCallback2}/>`

There is 2 solution for this.

1. you can do just as Widget.

```js
const Widget2 = ({itemDataToChild}) => <ModifyModal itemDataToChild={itemDataToChild}/>
```

2. Which I think should be the best approach since you can just rename your imports if was exported as default, and deleting the line `const Widget2 = () => <ModifyModal />`

```js
import Widget2 from './ModifyModal';
```

Keeping in mind that the second approach would result error if used for Named Exports. [Imports Reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)
For broad your understanding of JSX element and functional component I recommend take a look at their official documentation.
[JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html), [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)